# Postgres: query multiple records using a list of double keys

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have 3 tables:

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║      companies      ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ id                  ║
║ some_company_attrib ║
╚═════════════════════╝

╔════════════════════╗
║       people       ║
╠════════════════════╣
║ id                 ║
║ some_person_attrib ║
╚════════════════════╝

╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                            jobs                            ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ id                                                         ║
║ company_id – foreign key pointing to the companies table   ║
║ person_id  – foreign key pointing to the people table      ║
║ some_job_attrib                                            ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

From an external source, I have a big list of pairs of attributes, which reference **companies.some_company_attrib** and **people.some_person_attrib**, like so:

```
('some_company_attrib123', 'some_person_attrib456'),
('some_company_attrib789', 'some_person_attribxyz'), 
etc...
```

where each pair should match a record in the jobs table, so that the pair *('some_company_attrib123', 'some_person_attrib456')* gives me back the  record in the *jobs* which is associated:

- to the record in the companies table where *some_company_attrib* = 'some_company_attrib123'
- and to record in the people table where *some_person_attrib* = 'some_person_attrib456'

After looking around and not finding any solution, I am using arrays in the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs 
  INNER JOIN people ON people.id = jobs.person_id
  INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = jobs.company_id 
WHERE (
    ARRAY[companies.some_company_attrib, people.some_person_attrib]::text[] in (
    '{"some_company_attrib123", "some_person_attrib456"}',
    '{"some_company_attrib789", "some_person_attribxyz"}',
    '{"and_many_many", "more_like_these"}'
);
```

Although it works, it feels rather clunky and it's actually pretty slow.
I was wondering whether there was an idiomatic and more elegant way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it all depends on your scenario. If it is a one-off import, you create a junction table and use it for your joins.

```
CREATE TABLE people_at_companies (
  company_attrib TEXT,  -- whatever type it is
  person_attrib TEXT    -- whatever type it is
)

INSERT INTO people_at_companies VALUES
('some_company_attrib123', 'some_person_attrib456'),
('some_company_attrib789', 'some_person_attribxyz'), 
...  -- remember to remove the last comma :)
;

SELECT j.* FROM jobs j
  INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = j.person_id
  INNER JOIN companies c ON c.id = j.company_id 
  INNER JOIN people_at_companies pac ON
    c.some_company_attrib = pac.company_attrib 
    AND
    p.some_person_attrib = pac.person_attrib
;
```

Having such junction table might improve performance, and it allows creating indexes.

If the junction data is dynamic in such a way that keeping a junction table in sync is too difficult (a very unusual situation, I’d say), we can avoid the junction table but, at the very least, using `VALUES` instead of arrays is way simpler:

```
SELECT j.* FROM jobs j
  INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = j.person_id
  INNER JOIN companies c ON c.id = j.company_id 
  INNER JOIN (VALUES
    ('some_company_attrib123', 'some_person_attrib456'),
    ('some_company_attrib789', 'some_person_attribxyz'), 
    ...  -- remember to remove the last comma :)
  ) AS pac(company_attrib, person_attrib) ON
    c.some_company_attrib = pac.company_attrib 
    AND
    p.some_person_attrib = pac.person_attrib
;
```

You might have to explicitly cast the first row of the `VALUES` with the types of `companies.some_company_attrib` and `people.some_person_attrib` if PostgreSQL doesn’t figure the correct ones out. E.g.

```
  ('some_company_attrib123'::TEXT, 'some_person_attrib456'::TEXT)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dario, actually the use of VALUES instead of arrays  was exactly what I was looking for here!